# Tomcat installed on RHEL 7.2 homepage i,e 104.170.61.23:8080 is giving 404 , but http://104.170.61.23:8080/manager/html/list is working fine

Tags: apache, tomcat, rhel7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzgjn.png)I have installed apache tomcat 8 in my rhel 7.2 everything was working fine all of a sudden the tomcat index page localhost:8080 wont load, but manager page is working fine not able to figure out what went wrong.
Yes /  is missing how to get this back

Comment: Check if you have a ROOT folder, You seems to be missing ROOT folder inside  'webapps' dir, /tomcat/webapps

Comment: Yes ROOT folder is missing, but i guess it was not there earlier as well coz i did not delete any folders.

Comment: Maybe it was deleted somehow as part of some cleaning up etc. ROOT folder has config files for 'Welcome' page for tomcat. If you downloaded tomcat as a tar you can copy it from there into ../webapps folder and you'll be all good

Comment: That worked like a charm! Thanks mate

Comment: You welcome, glad you sorted it :)